# Перестают работать ссылки в SVG после вставки в слайдер

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, svg, asp.net-core-mvc

В стандартном приложении asp.net mvc core на заглавной странице показывается слайдер (bootstrap3 carousel) с четырьмя SVG-картинками:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="6000">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="~/images/banner1.svg" alt="ASP.NET" class="img-responsive" />
            <div class="carousel-caption" role="option">
                <p>
                    Learn how to build ASP.NET apps that can run anywhere.
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=525028&clcid=0x409">
                        Learn More
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="~/images/banner2.svg" alt="Visual Studio" class="img-responsive" />
            <div class="carousel-caption" role="option">
                <p>
                    There are powerful new features in Visual Studio for building modern web apps.
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=525030&clcid=0x409">
                        Learn More
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="~/images/banner3.svg" alt="Package Management" class="img-responsive" />
            <div class="carousel-caption" role="option">
                <p>
                    Bring in libraries from NuGet and npm, and automate tasks using Grunt or Gulp.
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=525029&clcid=0x409">
                        Learn More
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="~/images/banner4.svg" alt="Microsoft Azure" class="img-responsive" />
            <div class="carousel-caption" role="option">
                <p>
                    Learn how Microsoft's Azure cloud platform allows you to build, deploy, and scale web apps.
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=525027&clcid=0x409">
                        Learn More
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Я заменил svg на собственные и обнаружил вот какую вещь: если в svg вставить ссылку - то она работает только если открыть картинку в отдельной вкладке браузера. Если открывать html страницу со слайдером - то ссылки некликабельны.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         viewBox="0 0 1140 360" enable-background="new 0 0 1140 360">
    <path fill="#68217A" d="M0 0h1140v360h-1140v-360z"/>
    <text x="150" y="100" fill="white" style="font-size:250%;color:#ffffff;">ProjectTitle – project motto.</text>
    <a xlink:href="/Account/Register/">
        <text x="250" y="200" width="300" height="200" style="font-size:250%;">Регистрация</text>
    </a>
    </svg>
```

Что в слайдере мешает нормальному отображению ссылок в картинке? Как это исправить? Это вообще возможно? (Если посмотреть пример от майкрософт, то кнопки они рисовали поверх svg, а не внутри svg - может реально так лучше не делать?)

Update. При составлении минимального примера оказалось, что можно вообще выкинуть и слайдер (картинка вне слайдера) и весь бутстрап: проблема вопроизводится даже если воткнуть `<img src="banner.svg"` прямо в чистый документ:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="/images/banner1.svg" alt="Welcome" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Решил проблему ? У меня тоже не работает (((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Если посмотреть пример от майкрософт, то кнопки они рисовали поверх
>   svg, а не внутри svg

В этом случае нужно применить к картинке свойство  `pointer-events:none;` Тогда клик будет проходить через картинку и срабатывать на ссылке, которая внутри `svg`

`.img-responsive {
pointer-events:none;
}`

[pointer-events MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Какой у вас класс картинки посмотрите сами.

`<a xlink:href="/Account/Register/">` Если это у вас рабочий пример,то для ссылки нужно указать полный путь до страницы регистрации

`<a xlink:href="http://../Account/Register/">`

`xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` лишняя строчка в объявлении `namespace` `xml` не знаю помешает она или нет, но лучше убрать на мой взгляд

*Update по изменениям в вопросе*

- Разместил ваш файл на сервере.
- Добавляю его в html страничку с помощью команды `<object>`
- Далее этот файл можно использовать многократно в любом месте HTML
  странички с помощью команды `<use>`

```html
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://svg-art.ru/files/banner2.svg" width="100%" height="100%"> </object>
<svg viewBox="0 0 1140 360">
 <use xlink:href="banner2.svg" /> 
</svg>
 </html>
```

Comment: Тег интересный, никогда о таком не слышал, но направление мысли уловил. Правда, пока не получилось исправить поведение на желаемое: пробовал применять стилями к картике и вышестоящим элементам - но не работает. Потом попробовал убрать svg за пределы слайдера - тоже не работает. И последнее на чём я остановился - при вставке на совершенно пустую страницу html с чистым доктайпом html5 ссылки в svg перестают работать во всех браузерах. Начисто! Вот это уже совсем любопытно. Поковыряю ещё тему на досуге.